# Any easier way to do $name = $_REQUEST["name"];?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I'm new to PHP and am trying to create a form. I accept a bunch of parameters and want to process them in the same page. I'm not sure how to do this without a giant if-else containing the entire page as `if($_POST)`. This doesn't seem ideal.

In addition, I'm finding that I do the following a lot. Is there any way to shorten this? The names all remain the same.

```
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$gender = $_REQUEST["gender"];
$age = $_REQUEST["age"];
```

And I have a lot of lines which are just doing that, and it seems terribly inefficient

Comment: Why do you want to perform the renaming of the variables? You may access the value just by using the array. `<?php echo $_REQUEST['foo']; ?>` looks just fine for me. For the form: I use the following structure: <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ... // perform code here } ?><html><!-- here's the form ... -->....

Comment: GeneSys is hinting at that it's a good thing to know if your variable is coming from you or the user. With the rename it becomes hard to tell. You might want to consider some safety precautions along with the rename. "Rules of the modern world: Assume malice."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to do that. But it has a security downside: existing variables can be overwritten if someone would add variables to the POST header.

*Edit: hsz's solution is better*

Answer (score 1):

What process you are doing with if..else..if you have to post the code so that we can let you know how that can be shorten.

you can avoid the assignment for each variable using extract function.

```
extract($_POST);
```

But be aware that can overwrite your existing variable if the are named same as your input controls.

Comment: Dangerous move ! It causes overwrite your variables by user if user will set some values in address (GET) !

Comment: You really shouldn't. There's a reason that `register_globals` is off by default these days. It causes more trouble then it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using $_REQUEST, because it is a combination of $_COOKIE , $_POST and $_GET.
It becomes a security risk.

Comment: It does not. The "security risk" is a misattribution. The problem it poses is "cookie fixation", which depending on the use case becomes a usability inconvenience, not a security problem; particularly in OPs example. (I know that is covered only cursorily on SO, but still.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$_REQUEST` you should use `$_POST` here.

```
$keys = array('name', 'gender', 'age');
foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
  if ( isset($_POST[$key]) ) {
    $$key = $_POST[$key];
  }
  // optional:
  else {
    $$key = ''; // default value
  }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same as extract() though.

Comment: With `extract` you have no control over passed data.

Comment: You are not controlling anything here either. `isset()` is no security feature. With extract it's easier to apply a prefix to the incoming variables or array_map an escaping function.

Comment: I mean that if user will post additional variables like `$_POST['password']` then using `extract` function, it will be overwritten and `rapidash` will have no idea about that - it causes much more troubles that it is worth.

Comment: Okay, you have a point. You are filtering on variable names. But so does `EXTR_SKIP`. And `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` seems to me a better option regarding what OP wants. (Less code for extracting his vars.)

Answer (score 0):

Magic quotes? http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Answer (score 0):

For the first thing: Turn it around. Don't do

```
if ($_POST) {
 // Your handling code
} else {
 echo "No data!";
}
```

do

```
if (!$_POST) {
 die("No data!");
}
// Your handling code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), however, this means that you're bringing in a lot of variables that you (might not know about) int your current scope.

My suggestion would be to loop through your array and do something with the variables in there (e.g. - validation)

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $valu) {
   //do something with the variables
}
```

Also, don't use `$_REQUEST` unless you really want to check  $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. Use the proper array when accessing variables or people can send data you don't expect.